# Resolved failed! Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I've deployed my java application on GAP. in jsp i connect to external database hosted on somee.com. I successfully loaded the sqljdbc4.jar but when i connect to database i got the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Resolve failed: Request=LibraryProject.mssql.somee.com Exception=java.net.SocketException: Socket operation timed out: The API call remote_socket.Resolve() took too long to respond and was cancelled.
```

I put the driver inside the lib folder and use the following code to connect to database

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
String conURL="jdbc:sqlserver://LibraryProject.mssql.somee.com";
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(conURL,"mrquack","complete1");
```

the code looks fine and works well on localhost and gives the above error on appengine
please tell me a solution

Answer (score 1):

[Google App Engine Sandbox](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime?hl=en#The_Sandbox) does not allow to open a socket or access another host directly. sqljdbc4.jar is using `java.net.Socket` which is not allowed.